# Find the coordinates of the points on the curve $y=2x^4 - 3x^2 + x - 7$ where the gradient is parallel to the line $y=3x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I got that $\frac{dy}{dx}= 3$ 
(because of the gradient of the parallel line)

and then, I found the derivative of the equation of the curve to be $8x^3 -6x +1= 3$.

This simplifies as $8x^3 - 6x -2 =0$

From here, I simplified the equation and got $4x^3- 3x- 1= 0$

And I don't know how to solve this equation for $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradient of  $y=3x$ is $3$.
So by differentiating, we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=8x^3-6x+1$

Now solve $8x^3-6x+1=3$.

Clearly $8x^3-6x+1=3\Rightarrow 8x^3-6x-2=0$.

$\Rightarrow 8x^3-6x-2=(x-1)(8x^2+8x+2)=0\Rightarrow x=1$.

Thus coordinates of the point $=(1,-7)$

Answer (score 0):

If you have an "educated" look at the equation, you will see that $x=1$ is a solution.

For more solutions, you can apply polynom division.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the rational roots of such equations are found with [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). What it basically says is that all rational roots of the equation look like $x = \frac{p}{q}$, where in your case $p$ is a integer factor of $-1$ and $q$ is a integer factor of $x^3$.

Knowing that, you can guess a root ($x = 1$ in your case). That means you can factor out $(x - 1)$. It can be done through polynomial division or using [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method).

Given your example, $4x^3 - 3x - 1 = (x-1)(4x^2 + 4x + 1)$. Now what you have left to do is to solve a quadratic equation.